# Check a file on a different server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want my user to download a file which my script generates and put it on their server (this part has been built successfully). The goal is to verify that the user has the ability to upload files to the website they claim they own. I will be checking the root of the website so an example would be http://www.google.com/file

I then want my script to check if the file is present on their server. I figured, I could use some javascript to check if the domain of the user combined with a file path would return any different HTTPresponse than 404.

SO I looked around on the internet and tried a few things. Now here is the resulting function :

```
    /* DUMMY */
    url = 'http://www.google.com/';

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("HEAD", url,true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
         alert("HTTP Status Code:"+xhr.status)
     }
    xhr.send(null);
```

The url I used should exist. This should result in a 200 (or something along the lines of it exists). However, for most URL's I'll get an error 0 and following error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Could anyone help me out with my script?

Comment: You can't open urls on 3rd party sites using ajax if CORS is not enabled. The only option is to create php proxy script that will read the file and return the response.

Comment: Thank you, halfway through working with your comment to create a script myself another answer was posted here, though your comment was pretty helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest use php to check the same. If you are wondering about the issue you are getting read about CORS.

This is a simple example to do it

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

From here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064

Comment: I would suggest removing the `@` symbol and catch if there is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need Cross-Origin Resource Sharing enabled on the destination server(such as google.com where your file is).

To prevent vulnerabilities, you cannot execute JavaScript on just any foreign server. You can only do so on a server you own, by explicitly adding code in the config settings to enable requests from your client server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest (because it's the most portable solution) to put a proxy script on your server. Something along the lines of

```
<?php
  $url  = filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

  if ($url) {
    $ch   = curl_init($url);
    $res  = curl_exec();
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo json_encode(Array('success' => 1, 'status' => $code));
  }
  else {
    echo json_encode(Array('success' => 0, 'status' => 000000));
  }
```

You can then use XMLHTTPRequest and JSON.parse() on the Javascript side to analyze the result. You can also use the code to provide you additional data about the remote server that could always be useful.

Comment: On the client side you would only need to do a ```url = 'proxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com')``` where proxy.php contains the above code.